# Fatal error when running ping-pong parallel program

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, fatal-error

I had write my code to run ping pong parallel program. Below are my code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv){
    //t0 Start Time
    //t1 End Time
    int size,rank,msgtag = 1;
    double t0,t1,tmaster,tslave ;

    MPI_Status status;

    //initialize 
    int x;

    //initialize MPI
    if (MPI_Init(&argc, &argv) != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "MPI initialization error\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

    //communication between 2 nodes
    ///action process 0
    if(rank == 0){
        //start timer
        //master process
        t0 = MPI_Wtime();
        MPI_Send(&x,1,MPI_INT,1,msgtag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        //stop timer
        t1 = MPI_Wtime();
        //calculate elapsed time
        tmaster = (t1 - t0);
        MPI_Recv(&tslave,1,MPI_DOUBLE,1,msgtag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);


        printf("Master time: %g \n\n",tmaster);
        printf("slave time: %g \n\n",tslave);

    }else{
    ///action process 1
        //receive message
        t0 = MPI_Wtime();
        MPI_Recv(&x,1,MPI_INT,0,msgtag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

        t1 = MPI_Wtime();
        tslave = (t1 - t0);
        //Send message
        MPI_Send(&tslave,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,msgtag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

I can run my code without any error or warning. However, when I try to debug it, it show me this fatal error:

```
job aborted:
rank:node:exit node:message:
0:localhost:-101:Fatal error in MPI_Send:invalid rank,error stack:
MPI_Send<172>:MPI_Send<buf=0x003FFBB4, count=1, MPI_INNT,dest=1, tag=1,MPI_COMM_WORLD> failed
MPI_Send<97>.; invalid rank has value 1 but must be non negative and less then 1
```

Anyone know how to fix this fatal error?

Comment: You are probably debugging a single instance of the executable - it then runs as the so-called "singleton MPI" instance and there is only one process in the MPI universe and it has rank 0, therefore sending to/receiving from rank 1 is erroneous. There are specialised parallel debuggers like TotalView and DDT that are able to spawn a parallel job and then debug each process separately or collectively as a single program.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not running your code correctly (only launching one process). Make sure your `mpiexec` call passes a value greater than 0 for the `-n` flag. For example:

```
mpiexec -n 2 ./pingpong
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared value of `x`?
What is the value of `x`?
Run it with 2 processes.